# getting the address as a char string in c?

Tags: c

say I have the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main() {
    char c = 'c';
    char addr[50];
    strcpy(addr, &c);

    printf("%p\n", &c);
    printf("%s", addr);

    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

The above would print

```
0x7ffc241780af
c@@ //some gibberish
```

for the second line of the output, I am intending to output the char array so that it prints same as the first line.
I am wishing to have memory address as a string so that I can manipulate with it, but how exactly do I get the memory address as a char string?

Comment: `printf("%p", addr);` You use `%p` to print pointers...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `sprintf` function is used to "print" to a string. So instead of

```
strcpy(addr, &c);

printf("%p\n", &c);
printf("%s", addr);

printf("\n");
```

try

```
sprintf( addr, "%p", (void *)&c );
printf( "%p\n", (void *)&c );
printf( "%s\n", addr );
```

Comment: why is (void *) used?

Comment: According to the C specification, the argument for `%p` must be a `void *`. So other types of pointers need to be cast to `void *`. On most systems, it doesn't make any difference, but there are some weird computer systems where it does matter.

Answer (score 2):

Try this instead:

```
sprintf(addr, "%p", &c);
printf("%s\n", addr);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `sprintf(addr, "%p", &c);`